# How do I ignore errors with mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

When dumping a database, I'm getting

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `some_table`': execute command denied to user 'some_user'@'%' for routine 'some_routime' (1370)
```

and then the dumping just stops.

How do I make mysqldump continue when it runs into these sorts of problems? 10 minutes of Google has offered no help.

Here is the command I used:

```
mysqldump -u username -h localhost --port=4406 -p --databases database_name --skip-lock-tables --force > database_name.sql
```

Answer (score 34):

man mysqldump

```
-f, --force         Continue even if we get an sql-error.
```

Comment: Okay, I thought this was failing, but apparently it did work. The dump seems to have finished, but the errors just so happened to have occurred toward the end, so it made it look like the errors made the dump fail.

Comment: He has already provided the --force option in the command he showed us.

Comment: sorry didn't realize.

Comment: @Chad Johnson, a person might argue that if you cannot get a clean backup without using --force, then your backup did fail.  The force option will suppress errors that may be important.  Please do not  use --force in a backup script you will depend on.

Comment: This is just so I can get a dump of a database to work with locally. Nothing important.

Comment: Useful when trying to dump an invalid view getting the error `references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)`. Adding `--force` output the error but goes forward.

Answer (score 1):

AFIAK, you can't. You need enough privileges to run `mysqldump`. Why didn't you give `execute` privilege to the user that running?

Comment: Because my company forces me to go through another department :(